# mod_rewrite - exclude urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need a mod_rewrite to redirect all `http` requests to `https`, but I want do exclude some URLs

```
#   force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}            off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^secure\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !gateway_callback [NC]
RewriteRule ^.                  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

All URLs which match `gateway_callback` must be excluded

This URL should not be redirected, but it does!?

```
http://secure.localhost/da/gateway_callback/29/
```

Have tried to flush DNS cache in the browser, but the URL is still redirected to `https`

Comment: Change temporarily to `R=302` (found, instead of moved permanently) to test this, and try it with a different URI than you have been testing before (different integer value). I would expect what you have now to work and am going to remove my answer at least for now.

Comment: 301 and 302 give equal results

Comment: No, they don't, and he's right to suggest that. The browser will cache 301 responses and even if the redirect rules are changed, it's not going to be reflected. A browser clear cache + restart is needed. Or Incognito mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main problem with your config is that the REQUEST_URI variable contains everything after and including the forward slash. The third RewriteCond statement needs to be updated to something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/da/gateway_callback/.*$ [NC]
```

This should match the example you have provided. If the URI does not always start with `/da/` then you might need to put in a wildcard:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/gateway_callback/.*$ [NC]
```

where the `[^/]+` matches one or more characters which is not a forward slash.

I would recommend always using the regex anchors wherever possible as it removes ambiguity. The original RewriteCond attempting to match REQUEST_URI does not use them, which can confuse admins at a casual glance.

Also note that all related examples for the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives in the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) use the start anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Could the trailing slash be keeping you from matching?  I'm never clear on whether the trailing slash is preserved or not.  I suggest changing your 3rd condition to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/gateway_callback/\d+/?$ [NC]
```

Comment: have updated the question with new reg exp.. but `http://secure.localhost/da/gateway_callback/29/` is still redirected to https://