# mod_rewrite - Exclude URLs not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

This should be the answer: [mod_rewrite - exclude urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075835/mod-rewrite-exclude-urls) but not working!

I have next:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/registrationpassword(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://qat.example.com/ [R,NC,NE,L]
```

It redirect **all** *URL's*.
I need exclude the `/user/registrationpassword/` from redirect.

Redirect examples:

```
www.example.com                                   -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/foo                               -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/test/foo                          -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/user                              -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/user/registrationpasswordX        -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/user/registrationpasswordX/foo    -> qat.example.com
www.example.com/user/registrationpassword         -> qat.example.com/user/registrationpassword
www.example.com/user/registrationpassword/foo     -> qat.example.com/user/registrationpassword/foo
www.example.com/user/registrationpassword/foo/bar -> qat.example.com/user/registrationpassword/foo/bar
```

Apache version:

```
$ httpd -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon)
Server built:   Aug 13 2015 23:52:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\b` character:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/registrationpassword\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://qat.example.com/ [R,L]
```

PS: You certainly do not need `NC,NE` flags, as there is nothing to be either escaped, or compare case against.

You may also try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!user/registrationpassword\b).*$ https://qat.example.com/ [R,L]
```

---

Once that is done, redirection for `/user/registrationpassword` needs to be added:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://qat.example.com/$0 [R,L,NE,QSA]
```